# php codeigniter select results from foreach and save into an array

Tags: php, codeigniter, function, foreach

I have a php mysql query results as following...

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 52
            [sku] => 
            [name] => stone product 52
    )
    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 53
            [sku] => 
            [name] => stone product 53
    )

    .   
    .
    .   

)

Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 12
            [sku] => 
            [name] => stone product 12
    )
    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 13
            [sku] => 
            [name] => stone product 13
    )

    .   
    .
    .   

)
```

And I want the results just like as below

```
Array(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 52
            [sku] => 
            [name] => stone product 52
    )
      [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 53
            [sku] => 
            [name] => stone product 53
    )
     [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 12
            [sku] => 
            [name] => stone product 12
    )
     [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 13
            [sku] => 
            [name] => stone product 13
    )
```

in a single array

Please suggest me php code

Answer (score 0):

You should not be joining these results in php. Use [one query](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html#select) to get both sets of results, this will cut down on your db reads.

Comment: many thanks. but the results was from foreach loop and i have used array_push()

Answer (score 0):

You can use array_merge function : http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php

if you are working on an array that has arrays inside you can merge them with a foreach call

```php
$my_array=get_the_result_from_mysql();//Here how do you get the result.

$new_array=array();
foreach ($my_array as $row) {

$new_array=array_merge($new_array,$row);

}

var_dump($new_array);
```

I think this helps you.

Comment: If you can add little example that would be good and i will give you the +1

Comment: I'm not helping for +1 this url is so enough : http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php

Comment: but it returns nothing whats the problem?